# Why does my figure label seem pale?

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot a figure using pgfplots but even though I haven't changed any color in my document, but its labels seem pale. Why does this happen and how should I solve it?

Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \pgfplotsset{width=11cm}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[ybar,
     x tick label style={rotate=90, anchor=east},
 symbolic x coords={Karate(P), Karate(Rand), Dolphins(P), Dolphins(Rand),Football(P), Football(Rand)},
 %,Jazz(P), Jazz(Rand),Polbooks(P), Polbooks(Rand)
 nodes near coords,
 legend style={at={(0.5,-0.45)},
 anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
 nodes near coords align={vertical},]

\addplot coordinates{(Karate(P),0.378) (Karate(Rand),0.24) (Dolphins(P),0.51) (Dolphins(Rand),0.25) (Football(P),0.566) (Football(Rand),0.23) };
%(Jazz(P),0.356) (Jazz(Rand),0.1) (Polbooks(P),0.5) (Polbooks(Rand),0.21)
 \addplot coordinates{(Karate(P),0.369) (Karate(Rand),0.17) (Dolphins(P),0.47) (Dolphins(Rand),0.19) (Football(P),0.511) (Football(Rand),0.19)};
 %(Jazz(P),0.28) (Jazz(Rand),0.08)(Polbooks(P),0.46) (Polbooks(Rand),0.14)
\legend{$Q_{max}$,$Q_{avg}$}
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}    
            \label{FIG:8}
\end{figure*}
```

And this is how does it look:

[image: As you can see the borderlines and words are in a pale color]

I am using Elsevier's single column class template:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,12pt]{cas-sc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newgeometry{bindingoffset=0.2in,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,footskip=.25in}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\usepackage{lineno}

\begin{document}

% some abstracts and sections



\end{document}
```

the interesting part is that when I switch my class from `cas-sc` to `cas-dc` problem resolves:

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. There is nothing in the code you've shown that would cause this, can you make a complete document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` demonstrating the problem? I don't mean your entire file, but just enough of it to demonstrate the problem. It might take some trial and error to figure out how much you can remove.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I have added some parts of my code is it enough?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. By the way, this problem happens to all of my pgfplot figures.

Comment: If you add the first snippet of code into the second snippet, and compile it, do you still get the bad result? It looks fine here.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. No, if my document consists only the first snippet it plots the borders in black color but whenever I change cas-sc to cas-dc whitout doing anything else the problem resolves.

Comment: Are you able to make a minimal example that does demonstrate the problem? Have you tried other PDF-viewers by the way? (No idea what happens though, so the suggestion to try a different viewer might be stupid ...)

Comment: Something in your document might set or affect the color model for the whole document.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, MWE (Minimal Working Example) made up of your fragments does not reproduce your problem. So, below are only some off-topic remarks:

- figure label has sense only if figure contain caption, which had to be before label
- in preamble define used version of `pgfplots`, see MWE below
- that `nodes near coords` will not overlap with neighbor bars, you should reduce used font size (to `\scriptsize`) and increase distance between bars (as done in MWE below) or increase bar width (for example to `bar width=1.5em`)
- I would place label inside  diagram, for example at top left side of diagram
- please, always provide MWE, a small, compilable document, which reproduce your problem and can be tested as it is. Example of MWE is below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,12pt]{cas-sc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\newgeometry{bindingoffset=0.2in,
             margin=1in,
             footskip=.25in}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=11cm,
    ybar=5pt,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    x tick label style={rotate=90, anchor=east},
    symbolic x coords={Karate(P), Karate(Rand), Dolphins(P),
                       Dolphins(Rand), Football(P), Football(Rand)},
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={font=\scriptsize},
    legend style={legend pos=north west,
                  legend columns=-1,
                  /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=2mm},
                 },
            ]

\addplot coordinates{
    (Karate(P),0.378)       (Karate(Rand),0.24) (Dolphins(P),0.51)
    (Dolphins(Rand),0.25)   (Football(P),0.566) (Football(Rand),0.23)
                    };
\addplot coordinates{
    (Karate(P),0.369)       (Karate(Rand),0.17) (Dolphins(P),0.47)
    (Dolphins(Rand),0.19)   (Football(P),0.511) (Football(Rand),0.19)};
\legend{$Q_{\max}$, $Q_{\mathrm{avg}}$}
 \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{My figure}
\label{FIG:8}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which produce:

[image]

- if above MWE still produce gray ticks labels a possible solution can be to define `x tick label style` as

```
    x tick label style={rotate=90, anchor=east, text=black},
```